# Why does fscanf ignore the first string in my text file?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I want to read 2 strings and an integer from each line in a file. There is an unknown placement of whitespaces within the file. The first string is of unspecified length and second string is 2 characters. The code looks like:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char firstString[50], secondString[2];
    int number = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // Opens file to read
    if (fp == NULL) // Checks if file exists
    {
        printf("Error in opening file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%50s %2s %1d", firstString, secondString, number) == 3)
    {
        printf("First String is %s.\n", firstString);
        printf("Second String is %s.\n", secondString);
        printf("Number is %d.\n", number);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output always looks something like:

```
First String is .

Second String is AB.

Number is 3.

First String is .

Second String is CD.

Number is 1.
```

Comment: Aside: `secondString[2]` is not big enough to hold a string of length 2 as specified by `%2s`. There is no room for the null terminator. Similarly the first specifier should be `%49s`.

Comment: `number` ==> `&number`.

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is patientID? Edit your question. Also include a sample input file.

Comment: The _length_ of the _string_ may be 2, but the array _size_ needed is 3.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. The code is plainly not the code you are using. Don't leave out the `#include` library headers.

Comment: `if(fp == NULL) {perror(argv[1]); exit EXIT_FAILURE;}`  Three major issues that his addresses: 1) it gives the reason for the failure, 2) it prints that message to stderr instead of stdout, 3) it tells the caller that it failed rather than claiming success by returning 0.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read a string of 50 characters, then the array needs to be able to hold 51 characters. This is because in C, strings always ends with the `\0` character. So change the array declaration to this line:

```
char firstString[50], secondString[2];
```

Another problem in your code is that you need to put a `&` in front of `number` in the `fscanf` statement. Like this:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%50s %2s %1d", firstString, secondString, &number) == 3)
```

It is great that you check the return value of `fopen` and `fscanf`. Another thing you should do is to turn on compiler warnings. Compiling your code with `-Wall -Wextra` yields these warnings:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     while (fscanf(fp, "%50s %2s %1d", firstString, secondString, number) == 3)
                                   ^
warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main (int argc, char **argv)
               ^~~~
```

So as you can see, the warnings gave you a hint to the problem with `number`.

The other warning is not very important. Not using `argc` is not always wrong, but you could make your code a little bit safer with this:

```
if(argc < 2) {
     printf("No input file given as argument.\n");
     exit(0);
}
```

It is also a good idea to print error messages to stderr instead of stdout. Using `perror` is one way to do it. Another way that is very similar to `printf` is to just use `fprintf`. Actually, `fprintf(stdout, ... )` means the same as `printf( ... )`. So just use fprintf and specify stderr. Your first error printout could be `fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file: %s\n", argv[1])`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're probably getting an empty string in `firstString` because `secondString` isn't long enough to hold 2 characters *and* a null byte, and it so happens that, on your machine with your compiler, `secondString` is stored just before `firstString` in memory. When `fscanf()` copies `AB` and a null byte into `secondString`, the null byte zaps the first byte of `firstString` so that it looks (is) empty.

You'd be able to prove it by printing `&firstString[1]` with `"[%s]"` and seeing that it contains most of what you expected.

That layout is not guaranteed by the standard; it's just a plausible guess that explains what you see.  You either need to use `%2c` instead of `%2s` to get the `AB` into `secondString` (but then the name 'string' is a misnomer; it isn't a null-terminated string any more).  Or you need to increase the size of `secondString` to at least 3 bytes — allowing for the terminal null.  You have a similar sizing issue with `firstString`.  The 'off-by-one' difference between the size of the array in the code (N bytes, say) and the size of the string in `scanf()` formats (N-1 bytes) is irksome, but hallowed by years of tradition (it was thus in 7th Edition Unix circa 1978).  Changing it now would be worse than leaving alone, sadly.

You also need to fix the call to `fscanf()` so that you pass `&number` instead of just `number`.